# Images change in collection view when scrolled down and again up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionview` inside a `tableView`. Everything works fine until I scroll down the `tableview` and again scroll up the images of the `collectionview` changes I have searched it I know its because of `Dequereusable` cell but I cannot find any way to deal with this I am using `Kingfisher` to `Download image` through url. Here is the video of my problem [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gky471owD8w).

Code for `TableView`

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 5
}
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if indexPath.row == 0{

        let TableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TabelCell") as! HomeTableViewCell
        // let TableCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)  ) as! HomeTableViewCell
        //let TableCell  = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: nil) as! HomeTableViewCell

        TableCell.MainCellTitleLabel.text = MainCellTitleArray[indexPath.row]

        TableCell.HomeCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row

        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in

            if self.NewsArray.count != 0
            {
                TableCell.HomeCollectionView.reloadData()
              //  check = false
            }

        }



        return TableCell
    }else if indexPath.row == 1{

        let TableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TabelCell2") as! HomeTableViewCell
        // let TableCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        //let TableCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TabelCell")

        TableCell.MainCellTitleLabel.text = MainCellTitleArray[indexPath.row]

        TableCell.HomeCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        if NewsArray.count != 0
        {
            TableCell.HomeCollectionView.reloadData()
            check = false
        }


        return TableCell
    }else if indexPath.row == 2{

        let TableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TabelCell3") as! HomeTableViewCell
        // let TableCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        //let TableCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TabelCell")

        TableCell.MainCellTitleLabel.text = MainCellTitleArray[indexPath.row]

        TableCell.HomeCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        if NewsArray.count != 0
        {
            TableCell.HomeCollectionView.reloadData()
            check = false
        }


        return TableCell
    }else if indexPath.row == 3{

        let TableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TabelCell4") as! HomeTableViewCell
        // let TableCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        //let TableCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TabelCell")

        TableCell.MainCellTitleLabel.text = MainCellTitleArray[indexPath.row]

        TableCell.HomeCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        if NewsArray.count != 0
        {
            TableCell.HomeCollectionView.reloadData()
            check = false
        }


        return TableCell
    }
    else{

        let TableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TabelCell5") as! HomeTableViewCell
        TableCell.MainCellTitleLabel.text = MainCellTitleArray[indexPath.row]

        TableCell.HomeCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        if NewsArray.count != 0
        {
            TableCell.HomeCollectionView.reloadData()
            check = false
        }
        return TableCell

    }


}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 190
}
```

code for `CollectionView`

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {



    return 1
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if collectionView == self.MainCollectionView
    {
        return SliderImagesArray.count
    }else{
        var size = Int()
        if collectionView.tag == 0
        {

            size = NewsArray.count

        }else if collectionView.tag == 1 {

            size = EventsArray.count
        }else if collectionView.tag == 2 {

            size = PostArray.count
        }else if collectionView.tag == 3 {

            size = VideosArray.count
        }else if collectionView.tag == 4 {

            size = ResearchArray.count
        }

        return size
    }



}
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    if collectionView == self.MainCollectionView{

        let CollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell



        if SliderImagesArray.count != 0 {

            if let imgUrl = URL(string: "\(ImageBaseUrl)\(SliderImagesArray[indexPath.item])")
            {
                CollectionCell.MainCollectionImageView.kf.indicator?.startAnimatingView()

                CollectionCell.MainCollectionImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)

            }
        }





        return CollectionCell

    }else{

        let CollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

        CollectionCell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        CollectionCell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        CollectionCell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        CollectionCell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        CollectionCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        CollectionCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        CollectionCell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        CollectionCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        CollectionCell.layer.masksToBounds = false
        CollectionCell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CollectionCell.bounds, cornerRadius: CollectionCell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

        CollectionCell.tag = indexPath.item


        if NewsArray.count != 0{

            if collectionView.tag == 0
            {
                print("cell tag = \(CollectionCell.tag)")
                if NewsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("") && NewsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                {
                    CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                }else{

                    if NewsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("")
                    {
                        if NewsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                        }else{
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = false
                        }

                    }
                    else{

                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true


                        print("\(CollectionCell.tag) == \(indexPath.item) ")
                        if CollectionCell.tag == indexPath.item {
                            //CollectionCell.CollectionImageView.image = nil

                            if let imgUrl = URL(string: "\(ImageBaseUrl)\(NewsArray[indexPath.item].CollectionImage)")
                            {

                                CollectionCell.CollectionImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)

                            }else{

                                CollectionCell.CollectionImageView.image = nil
                            }

                        }



                    }

                }




                CollectionCell.CollectionLabel.text = NewsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionTitle

            }else if collectionView.tag == 1 {

                if EventsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("") && EventsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                {
                    CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                }else{

                    if EventsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("")
                    {
                        if EventsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                        }else{
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = false
                        }

                    }
                    else{

                        CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true


                        if let imgUrl = URL(string: "\(ImageBaseUrl)\(EventsArray[indexPath.item].CollectionImage)")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)
                        }

                    }

                }

                CollectionCell.CollectionLabel.text = EventsArray[indexPath.row].CollectionTitle
            }else if collectionView.tag == 2 {

                if PostArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("") && PostArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                {
                    CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                }else{

                    if PostArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("")
                    {
                        if PostArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                        }else{
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = false
                        }

                    }
                    else{

                        CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true


                        if let imgUrl = URL(string: "\(ImageBaseUrl)\(PostArray[indexPath.item].CollectionImage)")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)
                        }

                    }

                }

                CollectionCell.CollectionLabel.text = PostArray[indexPath.row].CollectionTitle
            }else if collectionView.tag == 3 {

                if VideosArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("") && VideosArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                {
                    CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                }else{

                    if VideosArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("")
                    {
                        if VideosArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                        }else{
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = false
                        }

                    }
                    else{

                        CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true


                        if let imgUrl = URL(string: "\(ImageBaseUrl)\(VideosArray[indexPath.item].CollectionImage)")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)
                        }

                    }

                }

                CollectionCell.CollectionLabel.text = VideosArray[indexPath.row].CollectionTitle
            }else if collectionView.tag == 4 {

                if ResearchArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("") && ResearchArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                {
                    CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                }else{

                    if ResearchArray[indexPath.row].CollectionImage.elementsEqual("")
                    {
                        if ResearchArray[indexPath.row].CollectionVideo.elementsEqual("")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true
                        }else{
                            CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = false
                        }

                    }
                    else{

                        CollectionCell.CollectionPlayButton.isHidden = true


                        if let imgUrl = URL(string: "\(ImageBaseUrl)\(ResearchArray[indexPath.item].CollectionImage)")
                        {
                            CollectionCell.CollectionImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)
                        }

                    }

                }

                CollectionCell.CollectionLabel.text = ResearchArray[indexPath.row].CollectionTitle
            }

        }




        return CollectionCell

    }



}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == self.MainCollectionView{

    }else{

        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeToDetailHome", sender: self)

        //delete below line and uncomment upper line of segue
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeToSeeAll", sender: self)


     //   let Tablecell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TabelCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let CollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

        print(indexPath.item)
        print(collectionView.tag)




    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView == self.MainCollectionView{

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)

    }else{

        return CGSize(width: 120, height: 140)
    }

}
```

Comment: Cells are reused. You have to set all UI elements in `cell/itemForRow` to a defined state. You set the image if `SliderImagesArray.count != 0` but you don't do anything if it's zero (and/or if `imgUrl ` is `nil`). Reset the image or use a placeholder. By the way your code is rather unreadable because of the bad formatting and secondly according to the naming convention name **all** variables and functions with starting lowercase letter.

Comment: thank you for your response i have solved it using scroll view